# "Login system using ms access" jbutton doesn't work

Tags: java, database, ms-access, button

So this code, is supposed to create a Login system using MS access, I'm using a Netbeans 8.1 IDE, MS Access 2010 for my database. The problem is, the actionlistener doesn't work, hence when i press the button, nothing pops up. Tried searching for solutions and i just can't seem to find it. I cant seem to know the mistake that i have done. please help

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;




public class Login1 {

Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;


JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
JLabel l = new JLabel("Username:");
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Password:");
JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
JButton b = new JButton("Login");



public Login1()
{
    connect();
    frame();

}
    public void connect()
    {
        try
        {


        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        String db = "jdbc:odbc:Database5";
       //String db = "jdbc:odbc:Database5";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
        st = con.createStatement();


         }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }

    }



    public void frame()
    {
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(t);
        p.add(l1);
        p.add(t1);
        p.add(b);

        f.add(p);

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try 
                {

                String user = t.getText().trim();
                String pass = t1.getText().trim();

                String sql = "select user,pass from Table2 where user='"+user+"'and pass='"+pass+"'";
                rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                int count = 0;
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    count = count + 1;

                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Found");
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Duplicate User");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User not found");
                }


                }
                catch(Exception ex){

                }

            }

        });
}


public static void main(String[] args)

{
new Login1();

}

}
```

Comment: do not just swallow your exceptions `catch(Exception ex){

        }`  - how can you ever know what is going wrong?  Print it out !

Comment: @ScaryWombat Hello, i just started Java, and i'm still a beginner, and i just followed this code through a youtube video, going back to you, will that help find the mistake in the code?

Comment: If you log your exception, then we will all know what is happening, so please change your code to `catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace ();}`  in both places

Comment: see https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/exceptions